# DynamoDB Streams and Lambda for transaction processing

Tags: php, transactions, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Can I implement transactions for dynamodb using streams and amazon lambda?

I have a game where players can join a team. There are 2 updates that need to be done.

1. Update team record (with Conditional - enough room in team)
2. Store team id in player record

I have a conditional write on the business side of things, but I am afraid of time outs when executing the second (third, fourth, ...) update that has to be done.

If I make only the first update directly from the PHP code and then use lambda to make the rest of the updates on other records and tables, will all the updates be made?

Only the first write has a conditional from the business point of view. So if the first update succeeds every update has to succeed.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I am curious myself for an application I am working on?

Comment: nope :(. What is your plan on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to think of DynamoDB streams as a kind of database trigger. If you're looking for DynamoDB transactions, please, take a look [DynamoDB Transaction Library](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions).

You can see an example [here](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx13H2W58QMAOA7/Performing-Conditional-Writes-Using-the-Amazon-DynamoDB-Transaction-Library).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This library has come up when I was doing research for this problem. It looks good, but it is only available in JAVA, so I would have to move all my backend which is in PHP to JAVA which I guess would take a considerate amount time :(.